# Python Run Inner Function Within Module

Tags: python, function, module, inner-function

How can I call an inner function within a Python module?

I have created a Python module. Within this module, there is a function. Within this function, there is a nested function. I saved the Python file with the name custom_module.py.

I have then called this module using the statement `import custom_module`.

I have then tried to call the nested function. I did this using the statement `custom_module.outer_function().inner_module()`.

This has not called the function correctly. How could I call the inner function from within a Python module, or will I need to create separate functions and not use nested functions.

I do not always want to call the inner functions when I run the outer function.

An example of a file named module.py:

```
def outerFunction():
    print("This is the outer function")
    def innerFunction():
        print("This is the inner function")
```

An example of the main file:

```
import module
module.outerFunction().innerFunction()
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the function definition (inner and outer)? Are you `return`ing the inner function in the outer function? If not, this simply won't be possible, regardless of if it's in a module or not.

Comment: Per your edit. Once a function is run, all variables in it's body are lost unless they are `return`ed and assigned to something. `innerFunction` is such a variable. You can `return` it with `return innerFunction` and capture it with `my_variable = outerFunction()`, and then call it with `my_variable()`. That is what @Chris 's answer is doing. Or do it in one call with `outerFunction()()`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use if statements within the outer function. This will allow you to only run the inner functions which need to be run. For example:

```
def outerFunction(parameter):
    print("This is the outer function")
    def innerFunction1():
        print("This is the first inner function")
    def innerFunction2():
        print("This is the second inner function")
    if parameter == "firstFunction":
        innerFunction1()
    else if parameter == "secondFunction":
        innerFunction2()

outerFunction(secondFunction)
```

The output of the above code would be `This is the second inner function`

Comment: I don't think this really addresses the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following presumably.

```
def foo():
  def bar():
    print("foo bar")
  bar()
```

The function `bar` in this case is locally scoped to the function `foo` can cannot be called outside of that scope, *unless* it is returned from that scope to the outer scope.

```
>>> def foo():
...   def bar():
...     print("foo bar")
...   bar()
...   return bar
...
>>> bar = foo()
foo bar
>>> bar()
foo bar
```

It's the same thing you'd see if you wanted to access a variable locally scoped to a function outside of the function's scope.

```
def foo():
  x = 42
  print(x)
```

You would not expect to be able to access `x` except within the scope of the function `foo`.